# Unable to connect to php socket(err_connection_refused)

Tags: php, sockets

Last time I've been recreating websocket protocol on my server. But recently when I connected to my server there was an error -err_connection_refused. I started analyzing packets that browser sends. I started with websocket, unfortunately there weren't any packets(sent to the server). Then I went a little bit lower to the http protocol and there weren't any captured packets too!!! Then I decided to check tcp protocol and noticed that there actually were a few packets, but server somehow didn't respond to them. Here's my php socket code:

```
    function go(){
    echo "GO() ... <br />\r\n";

    echo "socket_create ...";
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

    if($socket < 0){
        echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";
    }


    echo "socket_bind ...";
    $bind = socket_bind($socket, '54.37.233.12', 9080);     if($bind < 0){
        echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";
    }

    socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

    echo "Listening socket... ";
    $listen = socket_listen($socket, 100);

    if($listen < 0){
        echo "Error: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error())."<br />\r\n";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "OK <br />\r\n";
    }
    $socket_arr = array();
    socket_set_nonblock($socket);
    while(true){ 
      $accept = @socket_accept($socket);
      if($accept != false){
            echo "OK <br />\r\n";
            echo "Client \"".$accept."\" has connected<br />\r\n";
            $res = array("socket" => $accept, "handshake" => false);
            array_push($socket_arr, $res);
      Some code below(that you don't need)...
        }
  }
}
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
set_time_limit(0);      
ob_implicit_flush();    
ignore_user_abort(true);
$socket = go();
```

P.S There were no errors in console and all ports are already opened

Comment: Dont reinvent the wheel, libs like [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/socket/) you can do this with a few lines of code, also https://github.com/walkor/Workerman which is really flexible.

Comment: do they work with websocket?

Comment: by the way, you can see the result on: http://54.37.233.12/sockets/test

Comment: But, unfortunately it doesn't work on mac, as i described above

Comment: Yeah, their main function is websocket connections, a good example is phptty https://github.com/lcherone/phptty/blob/master/start.php which uses xterm.js over websocket to bash, in a 100 lines. Thes libs abstract out all the network layer an you only need work with the events like onMessage onClose etc, simples.

Comment: Why would WebSockets not work on mac?

Comment: I have no idea.